# How to erase redundant head ref in git?

Tags: git

My git log shows:

- 557b5b6        (HEAD, origin/tmp_branch, origin/master, origin/HEAD, tmp_branch, master) Fri Jan 27 22:51:49 2012 +0800 control RUN_WEEKLY

**`tmp_branch` is a redundant head ref that I would like to remove from my working directory and from the repository.**

What git commands should I invoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the local branch:

```
git branch -d tmp_branch
```

To delete the remote branch

```
git push origin :tmp_branch
```

(help.github.com/remotes)

Comment: ty for your quick response - that brings me half way there (* 557b5b6        (HEAD, origin/tmp_branch, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Fri Jan 27 22:51:49 2012 +0800 control RUN_WEEKLY) my origin still has a tmp_branch even after I git push

Comment: @kfmfe04 Selffix: you have to do the same on the remote repository

Comment: hmm... ...maybe I should have used `git branch -dr tmp_branch` instead (according to man pages)?  Looks like I can't do that now - maybe I should ssh onto the repository host and do a -d directly on the raw, as you suggested.

Comment: ty - works great - please add to your answer (via edit) and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -d tmp_branch
```

perhaps.